# Audio pops, crackles only for video ubuntu 16.04.1

Tags: 16.04, sound, kubuntu, video

I can play mp3s and other audio files fine but anything with video introduces clicks or worse, as of about a month ago.

I hear random audio pops on Youtube in Chrome and Firefox, as well as when playing videos (AVI, every other kind) through VLC or Dragon Player.

I don't know if it's the same issue or not but Youtube videos in Chrome (55) are almost unplayable, in case that's any clue.  If I play a Youtube video in Chrome I was initially get constant static/noise/crunchy sounds.  Sometimes if I fast forward the video it will start to work.  For some reason when I try this Chrome/youtube thing and the sound is just noise, the video seems to be playing too fast, in case that helps.

I've been on the same hardware and OS for years (Ubuntu 14.04 upgrade to 16.04 a few months ago, no probs.)  I've read many forums and tried things like the tsched=0 etc. to no avail.

Hardware:
MB: Asus P6X58D-E
Grahics: GeForce GTX 960
Audio: USB Behringer's UCA-202 running through RCA to Harmon Kardon 3384 but again, mp3 sounds fine so I doubt very much the trouble is in this area.